# Get json data from cloudant using android studio

Tags: android, json, android-studio, crud, cloudant

Hi i need to connect an android app with cloudant and get, post and put json data from cloudant using android studio but i don't know how, would you help me please?

I try to use volley to connect, i connect with sqlite but i don't know how to connect with cloudant

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView nombre;
TextView email;
TextView telefono;
Button button;
String json_url = "https://jesusjrod19.cloudant.com/gsus/usuarios";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bn);
    nombre = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.nombre);
    email = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.email);
    telefono = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.telefono);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,json_url,null,
                    new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                            try {
                                nombre.setText(response.getString("nombre"));
                                email.setText(response.getString("email"));
                                telefono.setText(response.getString("telefono"));

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"zaraza", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    error.printStackTrace();

                }
            });

            MySingleton.getInstance(MainActivity.this).addToRequestque(jsonObjectRequest);




        }
    });

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this would help you troubleshoot errors? --

https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/7.0/data/cloudant-nosql-db-api/android-cloudant-nosql-db-api/

If you're still having trouble, update your question with details...